# How can I make this kind of hole or drill in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm trying to add this component to my design in Altium but I don't understand this kind of "holes" (I suppose it can't be drilled properly.) I can't find any tool in Altium to design this hole. Is there a way to do it?

[image]

I have tried to do 2 holes and put on one over the other but on 3D view it can be seen this (i'm trying to d this from footprint editor):

[image]

Comment: These would be slots I believe you're asking about. You can use non-plated pads with x/y different values, and choose "slot" for the pad-stack. Then you might overlap two slots to get what you require, in this case a type of L-slot. The exterior of the periphery isn't clear from your drawing if they are counter-bored or otherwise if it is copper-plated etc.

Comment: As an FYI, these plated slots are actually drilled- using  a series of overlapping holes to get a fairly smooth internal edge.

Comment: The 3D view doesn't show reality. What you're seeing in that view doesn't indicate there will be any problem with the finished product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible ways:

1. Combine two slot holes:

[image]

2. Draw both hole and annular ring with lines, convert it to the board cutout (Tools - Convert - Create board cutout) and copper region (Tools - Convert - Create region)

In both cases, you'll need to override DRC rules. The situation will be easier for a first case because it's just one rule - hole-to-hole clearance.

Also, it'll be a good idea to warn your PCB house about this stuff because it doesn't quite fit into "standard" PCB features. If the PCB house won't know what you want to achieve - there is a possibility to receive manufactured PCB without slot plating.

Comment: First method might be more preferable because cut-outs don't appear in the gerber files. They are helpful especially for 3D.

Comment: Yes, if you considered 3D rendering your PCB. But from a manufacturing point of view, I’d like to suggest that interleaved slots are a more “classical” approach