# How to make an L shaped through hole pad in Altium

Tags: altium, layout, footprint

I need to make a footprint for a USB type C connector in Altium, and two of the shield pads are shaped like an L. Technically this is a component for Altium 365, but I'm not sure that will make a difference. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to reproduce the drawing. The closest I can get is adding two pads, naming them the same and overlapping them. Altium throws a warning when I do that though. [image: Drawing of connector footprint] [image: Best attempt at footprint]

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597552/how-can-i-make-this-kind-of-hole-or-drill-in-altium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make this kind of hole or drill in Altium?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597552/how-can-i-make-this-kind-of-hole-or-drill-in-altium)

Answer (score -1):

Look into a plated routed hole

Comment: Can you expand this answer?